# Is it in general dubious to call Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {}) in Subscribe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, orleans

I have a situation where I need to use a custom scheduler to run tasks (these need to be tasks) and the scheduler does not set a synchronization context (so no `ObserveOn`, `SubscribeOn`, `SynchronizationContextScheduler` etc. I gather). The following is how I ended up doing it. Now, I wonder, I'm not really sure if this is the fittest way of doing asynchronous calls and awaiting their results. Is this all right or is there a more robust or idiomatic way?

```
var orleansScheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
var someObservable = ...;
someObservable.Subscribe(i =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        return await AsynchronousOperation(i);
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, orleansScheduler);          
});
```

What if awaiting wouldn't be needed?

**<edit:** I found a concrete, and a simplified example of what I'm doing [here](https://orleans.codeplex.com/discussions/564648). Basically I'm using Rx in Orleans and the above code is bare-bones illustration of what I'm up to. Though I'm also interested in this situation in general too.

**The final code**
It turns out this was a bit tricky in the Orleans context. I don't see how I could get to use `ObserveOn`, which would be just the thing I'd like to use. The problem is that by using it, the `Subscribe` would never get called. The code:

```
var orleansScheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
var factory = new TaskFactory(orleansScheduler);
var rxScheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(factory);
var someObservable = ...;
someObservable
//.ObserveOn(rxScheduler) This doesn't look like useful since...
.SelectMany(i =>
{
    //... we need to set the custom scheduler here explicitly anyway.
    //See Async SelectMany at http://log.paulbetts.org/rx-and-await-some-notes/.
    //Doing the "shorthand" form of .SelectMany(async... would call Task.Run, which
    //in turn runs always on .NET ThreadPool and not on Orleans scheduler and hence
    //the following .Subscribe wouldn't be called. 
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    { 
       //In reality this is an asynchronous grain call. Doing the "shorthand way"
       //(and optionally using ObserveOn) would get the grain called, but not the
       //following .Subscribe. 
       return await AsynchronousOperation(i);
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, orleansScheduler).Unwrap().ToObservable();
})
.Subscribe(i =>
{
    Trace.WriteLine(i);
});
```

Also, a link to a related thread at [Codeplex Orleans forums](https://orleans.codeplex.com/discussions/560493).

Comment: `awaiting in order wouldn't be needed`. Could you clarify what this means?

Comment: If the operation is asynchronous why are you using a threadpool thread for it?

Comment: I removed the "in order" mentioning, and cleared some other points too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend against `StartNew` for any modern code. It does have a use case, but it's very rare.

If you have to use a custom task scheduler, I recommend using `ObserveOn` with a `TaskPoolScheduler` constructed from a `TaskFactory` wrapper around your scheduler. That's a mouthful, so here's the general idea:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory(customScheduler);
var rxScheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(factory);
someObservable.ObserveOn(rxScheduler)...
```

Then you could use `SelectMany` to start an asynchronous operation for each event in a source stream as they arrive.

An alternative, less ideal solution is to use `async void` for your subscription "events". This is acceptable, but you have to watch your error handling. As a general rule, don't allow exceptions to propagate out of an async void method.

There is a third alternative, where you hook an observable into a TPL Dataflow block. A block like `ActionBlock` can specify its task scheduler, and Dataflow naturally understands asynchronous handlers. Note that by default, Dataflow blocks will throttle the processing to a single element at a time.

Comment: This looks right. I tried to create the scheduler from ``SynchronizatioContext.Current``, but it's ``null`` in Orleans grain code and then I didn't figure out another way to make it happen. Though, I wonder now, I could use that ``rxScheduler`` there as also a scheduler in ``Observable.Create`` instead of, or in addition to, in ``ObserveOn`` (for reference, [Using Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242963%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)). I think it'd be interesting to ponder the effects in Orleans context, but that's for another time. I'll be on my comp in ~ 8 hours, my apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, instead of subscribing to execute, it's better/more idiomatic to project the task parameters into the task execution and subscribe just for the results. That way you can compose with further Rx downstream.

e.g. Given a random task like:

```
static async Task<int> DoubleAsync(int i, Random random)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(10) + 1));
    return i * 2;
}
```

Then you might do:

```
void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();

    // stream of task parameters
    var source = Observable.Range(1, 5);

    // project the task parameters into the task execution, collect and flatten results
    source.SelectMany(i => DoubleAsync(i, random))

          // subscribe just for results, which turn up as they are done
          // gives you flexibility to continue the rx chain here
          .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine(result),
                    () => Console.WriteLine("All done."));
}
```

Comment: "Is it in general dubious..." I would say that it is not only dubious, but **always wrong** to do so. James has the right idea here

Comment: Cheers @PaulBetts. I think you've managed to cut through my British reserve nicely there... :)

Comment: Heh, it doesn't hurt to ask, if it feels dubious. :) Indeed, I'm not sure how I've managed to gloss over the fact of SelecMany handles tasks nicely. So, I see the ``SelectMany`` here could also be ``.SelectMany(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {}).ToObservable())`` and I could put in the customer scheduler there. My apologies for the delay, I need to get to my computer on the evening (~ 8 hours) to investigate more thoroughly.

Comment: "Cheers @PaulBetts. I think you've managed to cut through my British reserve nicely there... :)". I couldn't resist, a colleague of mine linked in a business meeting: [Communication Patterns Around the World](http://www.businessinsider.com/communication-charts-around-the-world-2014-3) (cf. English and Finnish).

Comment: Love it! That's a useful reference!